# how sum & subtracting among multiple sheets in the same columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help! I have 6 sheets. All of them begin from A2:D. Each contains:

- a=cod
- b=brand
- c=type
- d= quantity

I want the result show in Sheet6 to be a copy of data from A to C. And D sould follow this formula:
 `D= Sheet1 + Sheet2 - Sheet3 - Sheet4 + Sheet5`

I search on the internet and I found this code. But I can't adjust it to do what I want.

Can anybody help?

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim My_array(1 To 5)
    Dim i As Byte, m%
    m = Sheets("sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row + 1
    Dim lr%, MY_sh As Worksheet
    Dim RG_to_copy As Range
    My_array(1) = "sheet1": My_array(2) = "sheet2"
    My_array(3) = "sheet3": My_array(4) = "sheet4"
    My_array(5) = "sheet5"

    For i = 1 To 5
        Set MY_sh = Sheets(My_array(i))
        lr = MY_sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
        Set RG_to_copy = MY_sh.Range("A2:D" & lr)
        RG_to_copy.Copy Sheets("sheet6").Cells(m, 1)
        m = lr + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The result I want is shown in the last image.

It copies data beginning shee1 to sheet5 from range A2:D. But the column D contains process of mathematics sum and subtracting between then five sheets.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome on board, Abdelfattah. I'm sorry to tell you that I could not understand anything from what you wrote. I even tried to correct the grammar, but I still could not know what you want to achieve. Please attach some pictures showing what the inputs look like and how the output should look like.

Comment: thanks  abdallah     i  edit my post  and  i attach the images   what  i would in the last image   i hope help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (Untested):

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim My_array(1 To 5, 1 To 2), RSh As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    'Change the sheets names if they are different,and signs
    My_array(1, 1) = "sheet1": My_array(1, 2) = "1"
    My_array(2, 1) = "sheet2": My_array(2, 2) = "1"
    My_array(3, 1) = "sheet3": My_array(3, 2) = "-1"
    My_array(4, 1) = "sheet4": My_array(4, 2) = "-1"
    My_array(5, 1) = "sheet5": My_array(5, 2) = "1"
    Set RSh = Sheets("sheet6")

    Dim r As Long, rMax As Long, i As Long, Fnd As Range, m As Long
    m = RSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    RSh.Range(RSh.Cells(2, 1), RSh.Cells(m, 6)).ClearContents
    m = 2
    For i = LBound(My_array, 1) To UBound(My_array, 1)
        With Sheets(My_array(i, 1))
            rMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For r = 2 To rMax
                Set Fnd = RSh.Columns(1).Find(.Cells(r, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Fnd Is Nothing Then
                    RSh.Range(RSh.Cells(m, 1), RSh.Cells(m, 3)).Value = .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 3)).Value
                    RSh.Cells(m, 4).Value = .Cells(r, 4).Value * My_array(i, 2)
                    m = m + 1
                Else
                    RSh.Cells(Fnd.Row, 4).Value = RSh.Cells(Fnd.Row, 4).Value + (.Cells(r, 4).Value * My_array(i, 2))
                End If
            Next r
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks  abdallah  but  your code not works well  it give  me  this in sheet6                               CODE     BRAND      TYPE                 BALANCE
vv            1200r24           G580              0                                                                           where is  the rest data  and  vlue  in column d

Comment: Would you upload a file for testing on Google Drive and add the link to your question?

Comment: it is  still not  work very  well   first  of  all  the  process of  mathematics  are  wrong  for  in stance  the   code AA1  should  the  value   is 320  not 250  equation this (250+120-50-50+50)      the  second  when run this macro  repeatedly    it   increases  the  value   you can test  that

Comment: Fixed both issues now.

Comment: thanks  for  your time  i  appreciate  your efforts  the  code  is  extremely perfect  as what  i would

Comment: Don't forget to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)